# Lazy Deferred List reaching maximum recursion depth

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I have a large list of documents to upsert into MongoDB (possibly n > 100000). I don't want to create 100000 deferreds all at once, but I don't want to execute and wait for each query sequentially because I have a connection pool to MongoDB and I want to utilize it fully. So I have a generator function that will yield deferreds to be consumed by a `DeferredLazyList`.

```
def generate_update_deferreds(collection, many_docs):
    for doc in many_docs:
        d = collection.update({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc, upsert=True)
        yield d
```

This is the code linking the generation of the deferred upserts, and the `DeferredLazyList`.

```
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def update_docs(collection, many_docs):
    gen_deferreds = generate_update_deferreds(collection, many_docs)
    results = yield DeferredLazyList(gen_deferreds, count=pool_size, consume_errors=True)
```

The `DeferredLazyList` is similar to [DeferredList](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList.html), but instead of accepting a list of deferreds to wait for it accepts an iterator. The deferreds are retrieved from the iterator while only having `count` deferreds active simultaneously. This is used to effectively batch deferreds because they are created as they are yielded.

```
class DeferredLazyList(defer.Deferred):
    """
    The ``DeferredLazyList`` class is used for collecting the results of
    many deferreds. This is similar to ``DeferredList``
    (``twisted.internet.defer.DeferredList``) but works with an iterator
    yielding deferreds. This will only maintain a certain number of
    deferreds simultaneously. Once one of the deferreds finishes, another
    will be obtained from the iterator.
    """

    def __init__(self, deferreds, count=None, consume_errors=None):
        defer.Deferred.__init__(self)

        if count is None:
            count = 1

        self.__consume_errors = bool(consume_errors)

        self.__iter = enumerate(deferreds)
        self.__results = []
        for _i in xrange(count):
            # Start specified number of simultaneous deferreds.
            if not self.called:
                self.__next_save_result(None, None, None)
            else:
                break

    def __next_save_result(self, result, success, index):
        """
        Called when a deferred completes.
        """
        # Make sure we can save result at index.
        if index is not None:
            results_len = len(self.__results)
            if results_len <= index:
                self.__results += [NO_RESULT] * (index - results_len + 1)
            # Save result.
            self.__results[index] = (success, result)

        # Get next deferred.
        try:
            i, d = self.__iter.next()
            d.addCallbacks(self.__next_save_result, self.__next_save_result, callbackArgs=(True, i), errbackArgs=(False, i))

        except StopIteration:
            # Iterator is exhausted, callback self with results.
            self.callback(self.__results)

        # Pass through result.
        return result if success or not self.__consume_errors else None
```

The problem is when the deferreds are yielded from `generate_update_deferreds()` their `.called` is already set to `True` which is causing `DeferredLazyList` to recursively call itself.

What's happening is:

1. In `DeferredLazyList.__init__()`, `self.__next_save_result()` is called `count` times (say 5).
2. Each call to `self.__next_save_result()` consumes 1 deferred from `self.__iter`, and itself is added as a callback.
3. Because the yielded deferred has `.called` set to `True`, `d.addCallbacks(self.__next_save_result, ...)` immediately calls `self.__next_save_result()` and this loop continues until a `RuntimeError` is raised because recursion depth has been reached.

I've printed a stacktrace before the recursion limit was reached to confirm that this is the cause of the problem:

```
File "/home/caleb/it/Development/projects/python/amazon/bin/feeds-daemon/lib/server.py", line 937, in update_many_docs
    results = yield DeferredLazyList(gen_deferreds, count=self.mongo_connections, consume_errors=True, return_results=True)
File "/home/caleb/it/Development/projects/python/amazon/bin/feeds-daemon/lib/twisted.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.__next_save_result(None, None, None)
File "/home/caleb/it/Development/projects/python/amazon/bin/feeds-daemon/lib/twisted.py", line 222, in __next_save_result
    d.addCallbacks(self.__next_save_result, self.__next_save_result, callbackArgs=(True, i), errbackArgs=(False, i))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 290, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/home/caleb/it/Development/projects/python/amazon/bin/feeds-daemon/lib/twisted.py", line 222, in __next_save_result
    d.addCallbacks(self.__next_save_result, self.__next_save_result, callbackArgs=(True, i), errbackArgs=(False, i))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 290, in addCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 551, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/home/caleb/it/Development/projects/python/amazon/bin/feeds-daemon/lib/twisted.py", line 222, in __next_save_result
    d.addCallbacks(self.__next_save_result, self.__next_save_result, callbackArgs=(True, i), errbackArgs=(False, i))
# Repeated until the RuntimeError
exceptions.RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. By the way, I am running Python 2.7.3 with Twisted 12.1.0 and the MongoDB stuff is really only relevant to understand the context.

---

I wanted the result from each deferred, but `cooperate()` doesn't return those so I added a callback to each deferred before yielding them to the `CooperativeTask`s:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import DeferredList, inlineCallbacks
from twisted.internet.task import cooperate

NO_RESULT = object()

def generate_update_deferreds(collection, many_docs, save_results):
    for i, doc in enumerate(update_docs):
        d = collection.update({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc, upsert=True)
        d.addBoth(save_result, i, save_results) # Save result
        yield d

def save_result(result, i, save_results):
    save_results[i] = result

@inlineCallbacks
def update_docs(collection, many_docs):
    save_results = [NO_RESULT] * len(many_docs)
    gen_deferreds = generate_update_deferreds(collection, many_docs, save_results))
    workers = [cooperate(gen_deferreds).whenDone() for _i in xrange(count)]
    yield defer.DeferredList(workers)
    # Handle save_results...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some tools in Twisted that will help you do this more easily.  For example, cooperate:

```
from twisted.internet.task import cooperate

def generate_update_deferreds(collection, many_docs):
    for doc in update_docs:
        d = collection.update({'_id': doc['_id']}, doc, upsert=True)
        yield d

work = generate_update_deferreds(...)
worker_tasks = []
for i in range(count):
    task = cooperate(work)
    worker_tasks.append(task)

all_done_deferred = DeferredList([task.whenDone() for task in worker_tasks])
```